# Batch import local user in Windows Server 2012 R2 with a CSV file

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, users, import

I've got a Windows Server 2012 r2 without domain and active users.
No Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT) are installed and no Csvde command.
Is there a way to import users from a csv file ?
Thank you in advance.
Alessandro

Answer (score 1):

As you don't mention an Active Directory, I found a powershell script example to create **local** username from an CSV.

```
CreateaHundredUsersFromCSVFile.ps1

Import-Module -Name LocalUserModule

If(!(Test-IsAdministrator)) { “This module requires admin rights.” ; exit }

New-LocalGroup -GroupName testgroup -description “for 100 users”

Import-Csv C:\fso\testusers.csv |

Foreach-Object {

  New-localuser -username $_.username -password $_.password

  Set-LocalGroup -userName $_.username -GroupName testgroup –add

}

Remove-Module -Name LocalUserModule
```

Code from [there](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/07/03/use-a-module-to-simplify-scripting-local-users-and-groups/)